# The reverse of a subset of a tuple or list

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have `x = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, and I want to get all the elements other the first two, but in reverse order, why is it supposed to be `x[:1:-1]` or `x[:-4:-1]` rather than `x[2::-1]`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation/509295#509295

Comment: The specific question asked here is not covered by the referenced answer. The issue is that when the stride (the third item in the slicing notation) is negative the function of the first and second indices is reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `arr[start:stop:step]`.

`x[2::-1]` would start from index 2 until the end of the array, so `[x[2], x[1], x[0]]`, which is not what you want.

If the step is negative, then the start defaults to `-1`. In python, `arr[-1]` would be the last element of the array, `arr[-2]` would be the second last etc. So `x[:1:-1] == x[:-4:-1]` (since `1 == -4 (mod 5)`) which is `[x[-1], x[-2], x[-3]] == x[4], x[3], x[2]`.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is very clear, although I feel that the design is counter intuitive.